# Why do my linked lists appear to point to same thing after clone?

Tags: java, clone

I noticed that when I first have

```
list2 = (LinkedList)list.clone();
```

I could operate on both lists independently eg. `list2.remove(1)`

But later when I do

```
list = (LinkedList)list2.clone();
```

when I do `list.remove(1)` list2 is affected too. Why is that?

**UPDATE**

My code http://pastie.org/2598096

Example input:

```
4 8
1 5 2 3
4
I 1 2
R 2
C 1 10
I 4 2

> javac Main.java && java Main < ./input/betterlist0.in 
[ 1, 5, 2, 3, ] -- [ 2, 1, 5, 2, 3, ] // list2 can be modified from list1 independently
YES9 8
[ 2, 5, 2, 3, ] -- [ 2, 5, 2, 3, ] // now when list2 is modified, list1 gets modified too.
```

I think its because `super.clone()` makes a shallow copy. But why then did it work the 1st time?

Comment: Please could you post a complete, compilable example that demonstrates this?

Comment: @aix, the code. http://pastie.org/2598096

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general you should write your own `clone()` function to achieve the deep copy you want. because java is not guaranteeing this.

Here is a quote from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clone_%28Java_method%29#Overview):

> The default implementation of Object.clone() performs a shallow copy. When a class desires a deep copy or some other custom behavior, they must perform that in their own clone() method after they obtain the copy from the superclass.

And I think [this](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#clone%28%29) is also worth reading.

Comment: I updated my question with the codes, any idea why it works the first time? ie. list2 was successfully modified independent of list1.

Comment: You are calling `super.clone()`. That is the same like not implementing it at all, because you send it to the super, but if you don't implement it, that's what the JVM should do anyway. So make there an actual copy and return it. Something like: `return ListNode(this._val, this._next.clone());`. Notice that this will trigger a recursive call, so don't use it with circular lists.

Answer (score 3):

```
LinkedList l1 = new LinkedList();
l1.add("A");l1.add("B");

LinkedList l2 = (LinkedList)l1.clone();
out("l2 after clone: "+l2.size());
l2.remove(0);
out("l2 after remove: "+l2.size());
l1 = (LinkedList)l2.clone();
out("l1 cloned from l2: "+l1.size());
l1.remove(0);
out("l1 after remove :"+l1.size());
out("l2 after l1's remove:"+l2.size());
```

that makes:

```
l2 after clone: 2
l2 after remove: 1
l1 cloned from l2: 1
l1 after remove :0
l2 after l1's remove:1
```

that demonstrates

> `.clone`

is working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

> when I do list.remove(1) list2 is affected too

No it isn't. Your observations are at fault here.

Answer (score 0):

Here's also what might be happening.

Basically, the list is probably not holding the actual object data, but references to them. In other words, it's keeping track of the pointers (a.k.a. memory addresses) to those objects.

In English, this is like saying "These houses are at these addresses", and you are storing the list of addresses in a phone book. The clone() might not be copying the house, but it might be copying the phone book

There's also the chance that someone might be storing "The phone book is stored on shelf B", writing it down, and handing someone else a paper saying that "The phone book is stored on shelf B"